# Making an auto typer from list view

Tags: vb.net, listview, sendkeys

I currently have everything working as it should except for one thing, right now I have the user type into a textbox, press the Add button and it inserts the text into the list view, when the autotyper starts it starts a timer tick with 6000 intervals and types the list but does not go back to the beginning of the list it repeats the last known phrase.

EX:
[image]

How can I make it start back over from the beginning if there is nothing left to be typed?

My code for the timer tick

```
   intervalTimer_Tick.Start()
  
   Dim SeprateLine As String
   Dim Separator As Integer
   If ListedItems.Contains(vbLf) Then
       Separator = ListedItems.IndexOf(vbLf)
       SeprateLine = ListedItems.Remove(Separator)
       ListedItems = ListedItems.Substring(Separator + 1)
   Else
       SeprateLine = ListedItems
   End If
   SendKeys.Send(SeprateLine)
   SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
   If ListedItems <> "" Then

   End If

End Sub
```

My code for button

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    
    For Each LVI As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        If ListedItems = "" Then
            ListedItems = LVI.Text
        Else
            ListedItems &= vbLf & LVI.Text
        End If
    Next
    intervalTimer_Tick.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks more like VB.NET than VBA. Please tag your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's great you've started coding in VB.NET. You are almost there, but I want to give you a suggestion. Don't store your values on your user interface - store them  in code off the UI thread. Using plain old objects to keep data makes it easier to write and read. Consider a `List(Of string)` to hold the items, and using a ListBox and DataSource to present the data. This allows for definite separation between what is UI and what is data.

```
Private ReadOnly items As New List(Of String)()
Private ReadOnly timer As New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf autoType, Nothing, -1, -1)

Private Sub AddButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddButton.Click
    Dim s = InputBox("Add item", "Add", Nothing)
    If s IsNot Nothing Then items.Add(s)
    ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
    ListBox1.DataSource = items
End Sub

Private Sub RemoveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RemoveButton.Click
    Dim si = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
    If si >= 0 Then
        items.RemoveAt(si)
        ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
        ListBox1.DataSource = items
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub StartButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartButton.Click
    ' different buttons / handlers for different intervals
    timer.Change(5000, 6000) ' 5s delay before first tick, 6s between subsequent ticks
End Sub

Private Sub autoType(state As Object)
    ' this ticks off the UI thread, so must Control.Invoke to run on the UI
    Me.Invoke(Sub() SendKeys.Send(String.Join(vbLf, items)))
End Sub
```

[image: example]

To stop it, just change the timer again

```
timer.Change(-1, -1)
```